# Count values inside an xslt array

Tags: xslt

I'm inserting values into xslt array and I'm trying to `Count` the each values inside it.

Here is my XSLT style sheet.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array" exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="input"/>
    
    <xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#10;'"/>
    <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
       
        <root>
            
            <xsl:variable name="a" select="A"/>
            <xsl:variable name="b" select="B"/>
            <xsl:variable name="c" select="C"/>
            <xsl:variable name="d" select="D"/>
            
            <xsl:variable name="array">
                <xsl:value-of select="$a"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$a"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$b"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$c"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$d"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            
            <test>
                <xsl:value-of select="count($array[. = 'A'])"/>
            </test>
            
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I'm getting below error.

```
Engine name: Saxon-PE 9.9.1.7
Severity: fatal
Problem ID: XPDY0002
Description: The context item for axis step ./A is absent
Start location: 14:48
URL: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#ERRXPDY0002
```

Suggestions would be also helpful..

Comment: You don't seem to do anything with the $input-as-map.
It helps when you also show us the value of $input.
Do you have also som xml as source?

Comment: I just updated my question.  when I run the xslt template it will ask for the input json. and provide as ```{}```. remaining everything is hardcoded in the program..

Answer (score 0):

What is e.g. `<xsl:variable name="a" select="A"/>` supposed to do? Bind the value selected from any `A` elements to the variable `a`? Or do you want to bind the string `'A'` there? Then you need `select="'A'"`.

And if you have some variables and want a **sequence** of various values use e.g. `$A, $A, $B, $C, $D` e.g `<xsl:variable name="sequence" select="$A, $A, $B, $C, $D"/>`.